# Entity Framework doesn't recognize navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am using **Entity Framework 6.0** with **code first**.

I want to create this table

[image]

This is the **User** model.

```
    public partial class User : IUser
    {
         public virtual string Firstname { get; set; }

         public virtual string Lastname { get; set; }

         public virtual User ManagerUser { get; set; }

         [ForeignKey("ManagerUser")]
         public virtual Nullable<int> ManagerUserID { get; set; }

         [Key]
         public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
    }
```

This is what I get when the table is created

[image]

Why the result is different from what I am trying to achieve?

What should I have to change to get the table as I want it?

Comment: You are never going to be able to create the top table. You have your foreign key defined as not null, but you can't have a not null self referencing foreign key.

Comment: hmm, you certainly can have a nullable self referencing FK with DB first, you would just set the multiplicity to 0..1, but i haven't tried that with a code first implementation.

Comment: removed the answer since it didn't seem to add value.  Have you looked at the Fluent Mapping API? it has an .HasOptional() that I think allows you to define a nullable FK, not sure if this would be an option in your setup?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved using this code

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
     modelBuilder.Entity<EFUser>()
    .HasOptional(c => c.ManagerUser)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ManagerUserID);
  }
```

It would be great to have solution using Attributes, meanwhile I'll use this technique